# Can Arcanist automatically configure access control through command line?

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

When use `arc diff` to submit code review to Phabricator, it generates a diff in Differential, however by default the `Project` of this diff is `None` which means anyone can view and edit this diff.

You can edit the access control in the Web UI, but it seems to me this approach is inconvenient. Is there a way that the access control can be done in a more automatic fashion?

Answer (score 1):

We control visibility of all Differentials by setting the Default View Policy here: http://your.url.com/applications/view/PhabricatorDifferentialApplication/.  This will apply to all diffs that are created.

You can access that page from your main loading page of Phabricator by:

1. Clicking on Applications on the main screen
2. Then Click on the settings cog symbol next to Differential
3. From there you can click on Edit Policies and set the Default View Policy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does help to limit access for only a group of engineers. At the same time, we need per project policy. What I did was to connect diffs with the repo( on phabricator), and set policy on the repo itself. Then all diffs, which belong to this repo, will get correct view/edit policy.